# How can I retrieve the phone number from Active Directory using User Principal Context

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

This code works perfectly to get the phone number from Active Directory using the username and password

```
    public string GetPhone(string domain, string username, string pwd)
    {
        _path = "LDAP://" + domain;
        string domainAndUsername = domain + @"\" + username;
        DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(_path, domainAndUsername, pwd);
        string telephoneNumber = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            object obj = entry.NativeObject;
            DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);

            SearchResult result = search.FindOne();

            var myEntry = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
            telephoneNumber = myEntry.Properties["telephoneNumber"].Value.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw new Exception("Error obtaining phone number. " + ex.Message);
        }
        return telephoneNumber;
    }
```

However, I have access to the user password only on the login page. I do have the User context being generated though that is accessible from anywhere within the application (`Context.User` which is of `System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal` type)

Thus, how can I get the phone from Active Directory using an already available `Context.User` object?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: I assume this is ASP.NET, but .NET Framework or Core?

Comment: It is .NET Framework

Comment: as I remember, maybe use an admin account to query the user's property, instead of using the user's account to query directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I overcomplicated everything and solution is quite simple

```
    private void SetPhone()
    {
        DirectoryEntry entryDomain = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain);
        DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(entryDomain);

        string lastName = Context.User.Identity.Name.Split(' ')[Context.User.Identity.Name.Split(' ').Length - 1];

        ds.Filter = "(sn=" + lastName + ")";
        SearchResult sr = ds.FindOne();

        string telephoneNumber = sr.Properties["telephoneNumber"][0].ToString();
        telephoneNumber = telephoneNumber.Insert(0, "(").Insert(4, ")").Insert(5, " ").Insert(9, "-");
        Session["UserPhone"] = String.Format("{0:(###) ###-####}", telephoneNumber); ;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `User` object you get will have the SID of the user. With that, you can use [the SID binding LDAP path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/binding-to-an-object-using-a-sid) in `DirectoryEntry`: `LDAP://<SID=XXXXX>`

```
var user = new DirectoryEntry(
    $"LDAP://<SID={((WindowsIdentity) HttpContext.User.Identity).User.Value}>");

user.RefreshCache(new [] { "telephoneNumber" });
var telephoneNumber = user.Properties["telephoneNumber"]?.Value as string;
```

The use of [`RefreshCache`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.refreshcache) is to load *only* the `telephoneNumber` attribute. Otherwise, when you first use `.Properties`, it will retrieve *every* attribute, which is a waste of time and bandwidth.

Comment: Getting System.NullReferenceException Object reference not set to an instance of an object on a first line :-(

Comment: Use your debugger and check which value is null. It could be `HttpContext`, `HttpContext.User`, `HttpContext.User.Identity`, etc.

Comment: It was actually because the user wasn't authenticated, now I get System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Security.Principal.GenericIdentity' to type 'System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity :-(

Comment: Are you using Windows Authentication? Or did you use Forms Authentication?

Comment: Using the active directory to authenticate, thus, putting the windows enterprise account into the login for the website

Comment: Got it to work!!! But changed your code a bit                 var winIdentity = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();

                var user = new DirectoryEntry(
                    $"LDAP://<SID={winIdentity.User.Value}>");

Comment: `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` will get the user that the application is running under, which can be different than the user logged into your website. It likely works on your development computer because it's running under IIS Express, which runs with your credentials. But when you deploy to a server, `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` will give you the credentials of the IIS application pool, which isn't helpful.

Comment: It sounds like you are using Forms Authentication where the user has to type in their username and password, right? My answer will only work with Windows Authentication. So you'll have to do it differently, but it depends on how you've implemented it. Does `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name` give you the username?

Comment: Indeed you are right, my application failed after a deployment :-( The System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name does work for me

Comment: Still struggling, just to give you more information, I am trying to get the phone during the single sign on

Comment: What do you mean by "single sign on"?

Comment: Maybe I am not naming things properly, but in our application the login is bypassed and user gets signed in behind the scenes, not through the login

Comment: That sounds like Windows Authentication. You should see a `<windowsAuthentication ...>` tag in your web.config. So go back to my second comment above and check which value is null.